# How to use CellIdentityGsm

Tags: android

I'm trying to use *`CellIdentityGsm`* by using the following code:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
    CellIdentityGsm cellIdentityGsm = cellInfoGsm.getCellIdentity();
    int MCC = cellIdentityGsm.getMcc();


    TextView view = null;
    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mCC);
    view.setText("MCC: " + MCC);
```

It works on emulator but for actual device, the application crashes.
API level is ok and permissions also ok

***********************Log|cat******************

```
    02-17 21:06:02.546  12608-12608/com.demo.aem.trial_1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.aem.trial_1, PID: 12608
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.aem.trial_1/com.demo.aem.trial_1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.demo.aem.trial_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 21:06:04.236  12608-12608/com.demo.aem.trial_1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12608 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hi, plz review the above logCat, waiting for your reply

Answer (score 1):

This is a just thought. I noticed you are a having a Null Pointer Exception. That means that most probably at this line,

```
CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
```

when you cast to (`CellInfoGSM`), actually `tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0);`might not be `CellInfoGSM` but maybe it might be WCDMA or CDMA.

So, perhaps `cellInfoGsm` is null.

I can suggest to you....to check first if  `tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0);`is GSM or WCDMA or CDMA before casting it into a variable.